# Sqlite2 ORDER BY not working

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm working in an old SQLite2 database and I'm running into an issue that's been driving me crazy.  The Database contains meeting events with the following fields:

ID(int)     MONTH(int)    DAY(int)   EVENT(text)     TIME(text)

TIME is a text field because it may contain 'TBD,' so I enter in the time by 24-hour

I want to retrieve the data and sort it by "date" and then by time, so that oldest-to-newest is shown.  However, when I do an 'Select * from Table ORDER BY MONTH, DAY, TIME' I get the following:

```
MONTH      DAY      EVENT       TIME
=====================================
  8        23      Dinner       19
  8        24      Brunch       11
  8        24      Meeting      14
  9        15      Meeting      19
  9        15      Breakfast    9
  10       11      Meeting      20
  10       11      Breakfast    8
```

Note that the last 4 records' time fields are sorted DESC rather than ASC.  If i do 'ORDER BY MONTH,DAY ASC, TIME DESC' then then last two records are ordered correctly but the 8/24 events are ordered 14,11.

I'm rather new to SQL so I don't know what's going on.

The code I use to retrieve the data in my PHP script is:

```
$stm = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY MONTH,DAY,TIME ASC";
$result = sqlite_array_query($dbhandle,$stm);
foreach ($result as $entry){  
 ****echo out $entry ****
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using Time as a TEXT field and sorting it ascending causes it to be sorted as a string ("20" begins with a "2" and is thus before "8"). In order to circumvent this you could either just use one DateTime field for the whole month-day-time stuff or change time to int and allow NULL values to represent TBD.

Comment: Your example says `time desc` but your sample code has `time asc`.  Perhaps this is simple typographic error.